# polynomial fractions $ \left(\frac{1}{n+x}\right)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with domain $\mathbb R_{>0}$ linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

My approach:

let $f_n(x):=\dfrac{1}{x+n}$. Then we want to check for which $\lambda_i$'s the following holds.

$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n} \lambda_i f_i=0$. By multiplying the denominator out we get the equation $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \left(\prod\limits_{k=0,k \neq i}^n \lambda_i (k+x)\right)=0$ (hope the indices are written right, I have the right idea but not sure how to write it down).
So now my argument is the following: $x+i$ divides both sides of the equation except for the term $\prod\limits_{k=0,k \neq i}^n \lambda_i (k+x)$ hence this must be the zero polynom. , wich is the case iff $\lambda_i=0$. This can be generalized for all $i$ such that $0\leq i \leq n$. Hence all $\lambda_i$'s are equal to zero.

$\\$

my knowledge of polynomials is really bad , hope you can help me with my proof.

Comment: It looks basically fine.